# How to get custom fields of XSD assert during XML validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, assert, xsd-validation

I have an XSD with a lot of asserts. The author of the XSD added custom fields to the asserts, so they look like this:

```
<xs:assert test="if(field1/@value != 1 and exists(field2/@value)) then false() else true()">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <das:rule_id value="60043"/>
            <das:rule_text value="Field 1 is set to 1 and Field 2 has a value, which is not allowed"/>
            <das:rule_type value="WARNING"/>
            <das:rule_fields>
                <das:field value="field1"/>
                <das:field value="field2"/>
            </das:rule_fields>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:assert>
```

When I validate an XML against this XSD, my validation message is the test (xs:assert.test):

```
if(field1/@value != 1 and exists(field2/@value)) then false() else true()
```

But I would like to output the values of the custom fields in `das` namespace:

- das:rule_id.value
- das:rule_text.value
- das:rule_type.value

Can you give me a hint how to do this?

My validation code (removed everything not necessary, checked that it is running):

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

[...]

public void validateXMLSchema(String xmlPath) { 
    try {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new Source[] { 
                new StreamSource(new File(MY_XSD_PATH))
        });
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        
        validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException ex) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(ex.getLineNumber() +": " +ex.getMessage());
            }
            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException ex) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(ex.getLineNumber() +": " +ex.getMessage());
            }
            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException ex) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(ex.getLineNumber() +": " +ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));                
    } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using xerxec for XSD 1.1 validation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.exist-db.thirdparty.xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <classifier>xml-schema-1.1</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Timo

Comment: Please edit your post and add your XSD processor and its exact version.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, I added the imports in my validation code and my xerxes dependency from my pom.xml. If you need any more information, just ask!

Answer (score 1):

Xerces XSD 1.1 allows to add custom a user defined error messages.

> "...This is done by specifying an attribute "message" in the XML
> namespace 'http://xerces.apache.org' on an xs:assert or xs:assertion
> element in the schema..."

Check it out here: [How to specify a user defined error message, when an XML Schema 1.1 assertion returns a 'false' result?](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-4)

> Following is an example of such an assertion error message:
> xerces:message="The number {$value} is not divisible by 2".